# AWSCLI what the default or initial value for --starting-token parameter

Tags: pagination, aws-cli

example bash command

```
token=null;
aws dynamodb scan --table-name MyTable --index-name nyIndex --max-items 5 --starting-token $token
```

I am doing the scan in the for loop, could not find what's the first/default value for `--starting-token`.

Tried token=0, token="", token=null, sample error message

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter ExclusiveStartKey, value: 0, type: <type 'unicode'>, valid types: <type 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **--starting-token (string)**
>    -- A token to specify where to start paginating. This is the *NextToken*
>    from a previously truncated response. 
>   For usage examples, see Pagination in the AWS Command Line Interface User Guide .

---

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html

---

For the first execution do not specify the parameter or the value. Collect the returned value of the token (if any) and use it going forward.

Comment: I am aware of this solution. I am writing a bash script with a for loop. Writing several lines just to handle this seems be ugly. I don't understand why they would not allow a null as starting point. Ugh.